# Не работает локализация Currency для русского языка

Tags: java, locale

Нужно выводить название валюты на разных языках, но почему-то для русского языка не работает такой код. Не могу понять в чем может быть дело.

```
Locale russian = new Locale("ru");
Locale english = new Locale("en");
Locale german = new Locale("de");
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance("AUD");
System.out.println(currency.getDisplayName(english));
System.out.println(currency.getDisplayName(russian));
System.out.println(currency.getDisplayName(german));
currency = Currency.getInstance("RUB");
System.out.println(currency.getDisplayName(english));
System.out.println(currency.getDisplayName(russian));
System.out.println(currency.getDisplayName(german));
```

Вывод получается такой:

```
Australian Dollar
Australian Dollar
Australischer Dollar
Russian Ruble
Russian Ruble
Russischer Rubel (neu)
```

Т.е. не работает для русского языка.

Также пробовал создавать локаль через билдер с указанием script - безрезультатно:

`Locale russian = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ru").setScript("Cyrl").build();`

Comment: Прошу прощения, с  forLanguageTag это уже эксперименты были, изначально было конечно new Locale("ru"). Код поправил

Comment: @Александр а какой вывод вы ожидаете увидеть, и почему?

Comment: @Regent ожидаю увидеть для локали russian вывод "Австралийский доллар" и "Российский рубль", т.е. по-русски, а не по-английски. Ожидаю это, т.к. язык локали установлен в русский, метод russian.getDisplayLanguage() выводит "русский". Для немецкого языка работает, итальянского работает, а для русского нет.

Answer (score 1):

Это очень странно, но похоже, что в Java почему-то полное имя валют не локализовано для русской локали и метод `getDisplayName()` выводит, к примеру, "Russian Ruble", однако метод `getSymbol()` выводит уже локализованное значение - "руб.".
Так же в Android при использовании класса `Currency` из пакета *java.util* ваш код  выводит локализованное полное имя - "российский рубль".